# Identify rows in two pandas dataframes that match partially

Tags: pandas, dataframe, comparison, rows, partial

I'm trying to add a column to a dataframe, df1, that states whether a row in df1 appears in a second dataframe, df2. This would be generally be fairly easy however, I really want a 4/5 match to count as well as a 5/5 column match.

That is, the entry in the new column added to df1, entitled "In_df2", would be a 1 if there was an exact match in the 5 relevant columns (out of 9) or matches in 4/5 of the relavent columns. Say this is df1 (with the extraneous columns removed).

```
df1_rows = [['555555555', 'M', 'Mike', 'Smith', '1970-01-01'], ['999999999', 'F', 'Jane', 'Wong', '1980-01-01'], ['111111111', 'M', 'Steve', 'Patel', '1990-01-01']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_rows, columns = ['SSN', 'sex', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'dob']) 


     SSN sex first_name last_name         dob
0  555555555   M       Mike     Smith  1970-01-01
1  999999999   F        Jane      Wong  1980-01-01
2  111111111   M      Steve     Patel  1990-01-01
```

And say this is df2.

```
df2_rows = [['222222222', 'F', 'Steve', 'Patel', '1990-01-01'], ['555555555', 'M', 'Mike', 'Smith', '1970-01-01'], ['999999999', 'F', 'Jeff', 'Wong', '1980-01-01']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_rows, columns = ['SSN', 'sex', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'dob'])
df2

     SSN sex first_name last_name         dob
0  222222222   F      Steve     Patel  1990-01-01
1  555555555   M       Mike     Smith  1970-01-01
2  999999999   F       Jeff      Wong  1980-01-01
```

Then it should return the following:

```
df3_rows = [['555555555', 'M', 'Mike', 'Smith', '1970-01-01', 1], ['999999999', 'F', 'Jane', 'Wong', '1980-01-01', 1], ['111111111', 'M', 'Steve', 'Patel', '1990-01-01', 0]]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3_rows, columns = ['SSN', 'sex', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'In_df2'])
df3

     SSN sex first_name last_name         dob  In_df2
0  555555555   M       Mike     Smith  1970-01-01       1
1  999999999   F       Jane      Wong  1980-01-01       1
2  111111111   M      Steve     Patel  1990-01-01       0
```

The column "In_df2" has a 1 in the "0" row because there is an exact match in df2 for row "0" in df1. It has a 1 in the "1" row because there is a 4/5 match in df2 for row "1" in df1. It has a 0 in the "2" row because there is only a 3/5 match in df2 for row "2" in df1.

I've written code to do this manually (see below), but I'm something of a newbie at coding and, predictably, it's super slow. I've searched and can't find a package that seems to handle this partial matching.

One last thing, the output doesn't have to be a column like I'm adding. I really just want to identify all rows in df1 that don't have a 4/5 or 5/5 partner in df2.

Thanks for any and all suggestions!

My code:

```
def row_compare(row1, row2):
    
    count = 0

    if row1.ssn == row2.ssn:
        count += 1
    if row1.dob == row2.dob:
        count += 1
    if row1.sex == row2.sex:
        count += 1
    if row1.first_name == row2.first_name:
        count += 1
    if row1.last_name== row2.last_name:
        count += 1
        
    if count >= 4:
        out = 1
    else:
        out = 0
        
    return out
```

followed by:

```
def row_to_df_compare(row1, df):
    
    df['In_Other'] = df.apply(lambda row2 : row_compare(row1, row2), axis = 1)
    if df.sum().In_Other > 0:
        out = 1
    else:
        out = 0
    return out
```

and finally by:

```
df1['In_df2'] = df1.apply(lambda row : row_to_df_compare(row, df2), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

a colleague of mine came up with this answer which seems to work in the example dataframes that I'm using:

```
from itertools import combinations 

df1['n_duplicates'] = 0

for columns in combinations(df2.columns, 4):
    columns = list(columns)
    df_concat = pd.concat([df1[columns], df2[columns]], ignore_index = True, sort = False).reset_index(drop=True)
    df1['n_duplicates'] += df_concat.duplicated(keep = False).astype(int).iloc[:df1.shape[0]]

df1_dedup = df1[df1['n_duplicates'] < 4]
```